# Mongo Setting Path

Tags: mongodb, macos, path

I am currently running macOS Sierra (latest version) and I have zshell installed. I have tried to follow the steps to install MongoDB Community Edition Manually by using the following commands after downloading the binaries from the MongoDB Download Center.

1. **tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.2.tgz**
2. **mkdir -p mongodb**
3. **cp -R -n mongodb-osx-ssl-x86_64-3.6.2/ mongodb**
4. **export PATH=mongodb-install-directory/bin:$PATH**

On step 4, my mongodb install directory path is in **/Users/(my username)/mongodb**. Therefore, I have run the following command:

- **export PATH=/Users/(my username)/mongodb/bin:$PATH**

From the (my username) directory, I tried to run mongod and got the message **zsh: command not found: mongod**. However, when I go into **/Users/(my username)/mongodb/bin** and run **./mongod**, everything works except for my data path not being set.

From here, I have tried to set the db path by running the following command:

- **./mongod --dbpath /Users/(my username)/mongodb/data/db**

Then I ran **./mongod** and the data path was not found. What am I doing wrong? I even tried to install MongoDB Community Edition with Homebrew and the same errors popped up.

I am not sure if this would make a difference, but I have installed vagrant in the past and I was able to use MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest re-install MongoDB once again, use brew

`brew update`

```
brew install mongodb
```

Comment: I wonder if this would make a difference. I check my .bash_profile, it is  export PATH=/usr/local/mongodb/bin:$PATH